# Count repeated columns of a line, print all lines and their count

Tags: bash, awk, sed, large-files, uniq

I want:

```
$ cat file
ABCDEFG, XXX
ABCDEFG, YYY
ABCDEFG, ZZZ
AAAAAAA, XZY
BBBBBBB, XYZ
CCCCCCC, YXZ
DDDDDDD, YZX
CDEFGHI, ZYX
CDEFGHI, XZY

$ cat file | magic
3 ABCDEFG, XXX
3 ABCDEFG, YYY
3 ABCDEFG, ZZZ
1 AAAAAAA, XZY
1 BBBBBBB, XYZ
1 CCCCCCC, YXZ
1 DDDDDDD, YZX
2 CDEFGHI, ZYX
2 CDEFGHI, XZY
```

So, pre-sorted file goes in, identify repeats in the first column, count the number of lines of this repeat, print the repeat count plus all the repeated lines and their content, including whatever is in column 2, which can be anything and is not relevant to the unique count.
Two problems:

1) get the effect of `uniq -c`, but without deleting the duplicates.

My really "hacky" `sed -e` solution after searching online was this:

```
cat file | cut -d',' -f1 | uniq -c | sed -E -e 's/([0-9][0-9]*) (.*)/echo $(yes \1 \2 | head -\1)/;e' | sed -E 's/ ([0-9])/;\1/g' | tr ';' '\n'
```

I was surprised to see things like `head -\1` working, but well great. However, I feel like there should be a much simpler solution to the problem.

2) The above get's rid of the second column. I could just run my code first, and then `paste` it to my second column in the original file, but the file is massive and I want things to be as speed efficient as possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One in awk. Pretty tired so not fully tested. I hope it works, good night:

```
$ awk -F, '
$1!=p {
    for(i=1;i<c;i++)
        print c-1,a[i]
    c=1
}
{
    a[c++]=$0
    p=$1
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<c;i++)
        print c-1,a[i]
}' file
```

Output:

```
3 ABCDEFG,XXX
3 ABCDEFG,YYY
3 ABCDEFG,ZZZ
1 AAAAAAA,XZY
1 BBBBBBB,XYZ
1 CCCCCCC,YXZ
1 DDDDDDD,YZX
2 CDEFGHI,ZYX
2 CDEFGHI,XZY
```

Comment: It worked for the example, but I made a mistake and my file actually doesn't contain a space after the comma, which made your solution fail. I'm totally ignorant in awk, if you provide me the correction to deal with the missing space I'll benchmark your solution

Comment: @Max I kinda fixed it. This one is way better than the accepted one in memory efficiency and thus performance

Comment: The corrected version works for my file without spaces, and was about twice as fast the solution by Steve. For a 10gb file was about 5 min

Comment: @Max It's twice as fast as it only processes the file once.

Comment: @oguzismail: Won't that depend on the number of duplicates in the first column? For example, if a single value in the first field makes up 80% of the values in the file, this solution will store 80% of the file in memory. Unfortunately, I don't think there's anyway to get away from that using this approach.

Comment: @Steve it's still better than keeping 100% of it in memory

Comment: @oguzismail: I'm not sure that I understand your last point. If the input file contains only a single value in the first field - you will end up storing the entire file in memory. In terms of memory efficiency, this is the worst case scenario. My point was that this solution could become the least memory efficient solution depending on the number of duplicates in the first field. That doesn't necessarily make it a bad solution, but there's a "gotcha" in there for the unwary who may not know their inputs. The "gotcha" of course is when your OOM killer kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) that passes the file twice. On the first pass, use an associative array to store the counts of the first column. On the second pass, print the array value and the line itself:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1]++; next } { print a[$1], $0 }' file{,}
```

Results:

```
3 ABCDEFG, XXX
3 ABCDEFG, YYY
3 ABCDEFG, ZZZ
1 AAAAAAA, XZY
1 BBBBBBB, XYZ
1 CCCCCCC, YXZ
1 DDDDDDD, YZX
2 CDEFGHI, ZYX
2 CDEFGHI, XZY
```

Comment: This works, but took about twice as long as the solution by James Brown. For a 10gb file was anyway <10min

Comment: @Max: No worries - it's slower because it reads the input file twice. One advantage is that it doesn't require sorted input. It wasn't clear to me whether you needed or wanted sorted output.

Comment: @Max: It's also more predictable in terms of it's memory use. Please see my comments above.